# No Java implementations for arrayset

Tags: java, set

How come Java provides several different implementations of the `Set` type, including `HashSet` and `TreeSet` and ***not*** `ArraySet`?

Comment: How would that be useful?

Comment: What is an ArraySet? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @BrinJ A set implemented using an array as backend, which doesn't make sense from an algorithmic point of view. See answers.

Comment: Just because there's an `ArrayList` doesn't mean there has to be an `ArraySet` too. I could just as well ask: why isn't there a `HashList` , since there's a `HashSet`? Or why not a `TreeList`? Not all combinations of those words makes sense.

Comment: @Jesper But if you look at Peter Lawrey's answer there is actually an `[*]ArraySet` :-)

Comment: @Jesper sorry if i offended you or something.. i was just curious and im new to java :/

Comment: @maba And as he says, it's not particularly useful...

Comment: @user1595291 You didn't offend me at all. I hope my answer was useful.

Comment: ArraySet would be useful for performance for very small Sets.  HashSet is slower than ArraySet for quantities < 7 iirc.  That is, if I have an object that expects a Set, but I know the Set will be very small, it would make sense to provide this Set value using an ArraySet.

Comment: Agree with Pxtl. Having Set implementation backed by a sorted array is a pretty good tradeoff in terms of memory vs lookup performance. That's why it's heavily used in Android, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33026128/1129542

Comment: For anyone wondering why you'd want this, I have to pass a `Set<Long>` into a method and I have a `List<Long>`.  I know that what I pass in is going to be iterated over and not probed for members or mutated.  So I'd prefer to do: `set = new ArraySet<>( list );`. It could right-size the array and then it'd be both efficient and of the correct type.

Answer (score 17):

A set based solely on an array of elements in no particular order would always have O(n) time for a containment check. It wouldn't be terribly useful, IMO. When would you *want* to use that instead of `HashSet` or `TreeSet`?

The most useful aspect of an array is that you can get to an element with a particular *index* extremely quickly. That's not terribly relevant when it comes to sets.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate... there are cases where an array which keeps itself sorted and guarantees uniqueness would be very useful.  Sure the performance would be poor on update, but it would be excellent on random access by index, so if the set is mostly read, then performance would not be an issue.  I'd like one for backing android's BaseAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

Comment: @couling: It would be fine for "read by index" - but that's not a natural operation for a set. It wouldn't be too hard to write such a collection, but it would have odd performance characteristics...

Comment: Wouldn't an ArraySet be useful given a small set and expensive allocations? Though I suppose given the set is small, there wouldn't be many allocations.

Comment: @nmr: Can't say I've ever wanted that myself - I'd just use a HashSet.

Comment: What about a real-time system, where you're trying to strictly bound execution time? Seems like it could valuable in theory, but appears worthless in practice.

Comment: @nmr: Yes, there will always be edge cases like that - but when you have a "no dynamic allocation" policy all kinds of normal best practices go to the wall.

Comment: Many Java collections have a large per element memory overhead. I'm counting to 28 bytes for `HashSet` (4 bytes per word). An array base set would only require 4 bytes per element. And in many cases the disadvantages are not so bad, such as when you do few modifications and can keep it sorted, or when you have many small sets.

Comment: O(n) vs O(1) isnt' the whole story.  The hashing cost matters - for very small sets with complicated hashing functions, linear search is faster than a hashtable.  Obviously if you expect to have >8 elements in your set, it's time to use a hashset.  Otherwise an ArraySet makes sense, especially if you know that most cases the "best case" result of hitting the first element in the set is expected to be the most common.

Comment: I wrote an `ArraySet` for a case where sets tend to contain a small number of elements, and are iterated far more often than they are modified.  Iteration is about 30% faster than `HashSet`.

Answer (score 11):

There is [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) which is a set backed by an array.

This is not particularly useful as its performance is not great for large collections.

Comment: That is the closest one can get regarding the name anyway :-)

Comment: CopyOnWriteArraySet implements Set and is backed by a CopyOnWriteArrayList. [Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.java?av=h#CopyOnWriteArraySet)

Comment: @Link and CopyOnWriteArrayList actually uses an `Object[]`

Comment: I find it useful in testing to be able to iterate over the contents of a set with a guarantee that the order will be the same as order the contents were added. This isn't the case for any other set implementation I know of.

Answer (score 3):

Android has [android.util.ArraySet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArraySet.html) (introduced in API level 23) and [android.util.ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html) (introduced in API level 19).

Answer (score 2):

Actually the concrete implementation of Set does not make any sense. Any set stores elements and guaranties their uniqueness. 
I cannot be sure but it sounds that you want Set implementation that preserves order of elements. If I am right use `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Set` interface has no get-by-index method, such as `List.get(int)`, so there's no use suggesting Set can have array like properties.

Ultimately, all "grouping" classes use arrays under the hood to store their elements, but that doesn't mean you have to expose methods for accessing the array.

Comment: Is `LinkedList` backed by an array?

Comment: @JacobRaihle Good point, but I don't consider that a "grouping" class. It's just a reference to the head of a chain of nodes, rather than a group of nodes. The key is who has the reference to the elements: A LinkedList does't have a reference to all its elements - it only has a reference to the head.

Comment: Alright, for a minute I was really worried about my understanding of the class...

Comment: `LinkedList` is one example. HashMap does use arrays, but quite differently than just storing elements. There even might be backends like files or databases, simply depending on what is to be done with the elements in it.

Comment: @kw4nta A `HashMap` uses an array for its entries: `Entry[] table`. Ultimately, every "value" is stored in a field that is either a primitive or an array of primitives. There just aren't any other options.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides multiple implementations of its `Collection` Interfaces that allow for best performance. `ArrayList` performs good on many `List` operations.

For `Set` Operations, which allways require uniquness different implementations offer better performance. If implemented using an array, any modification operation would have to run through all the array elements to check if it is allready in the Set. HashSet and TreeSet simplyfy this check greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement it yourself....now granted there probably is only one extremely, extremely limited case where it would be useful(and in that case you could use better data structures anyway) and that is where you have a very large set that almost never changes then an array set would take up SLIGHTLY less memory(no extra pointers) and you would have ever so slightly faster enumeration of the whole set... If you keep the array sorted then you can still get O(lg n) search time.

However those differences are purely academic.  In the real world you would never really want such a beast

Answer (score 0):

Consider [indexed-tree-map](http://code.google.com/p/indexed-tree-map/) , you will be able to access elements by index and get index of elements while keeping the sort order. Duplicates can be put into arrays as values under the same key.